# Why is 192.168.1.0 needed in route table?

Tags: networking, routing, gateway

My home network is configured as follows:

```
Computer -- Route -- Internet
```

If I run `route` on my computer, I see

```
~ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
```

My question is that since all packets matching 192.168.1.0 will be directed to 0.0.0.0, why is the first entry needed? Would removing the entry cause any problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entry doesn't point to 0.0.0.0; rather, it points to the `eth0` interface. Without it, the system wouldn't know which interface to use when sending packets to 192.168.1.1 and other computers in the same subnetwork.

Remember also that computers in 192.168.1.0 are *not* behind the gateway; they can be reached directly.

Comment: But when I remove the first entry, I can still ping google.com. Why is this happening?

Comment: @Usavich: Because the first entry doesn't match Google's address and wouldn't have been used anyway. It is only for communications with 192.168.1.*.